# Typescript : setter and inheritance on interfaces

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface, setter

I have two typescript interfaces, one of which inherits from the other (in the final application I will have several levels of inheritance).
I want to have a method to modify the properties of all types of objects that inherit from my main class. Be careful, in this method, the name of the property is not necessarily identical to a property name declared in my interface.
Also, when entering my modifier, I don't know what type of object I am passing initially. If I don't do a single modifier for all objects that inherit from a class, I'm afraid I might have to duplicate code.

I thought to make a map or I associate a key which would be the property and in value of a function which would be my modifier, but that does not seem to be able to be done (typescript control on the types of objects).

Sample code :

```
interface PositionnedItem {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

interface BoxedItem extends PositionnedItem {
    tickness: number;
}

function setProperty<T extends PositionnedItem>(item: T, property: string, value: number): void {
    if(property === 'raz') {
        item.x = 0;
        item.y = 0;
        item.tickness = 0;
    } else if(property === 'all') {
        item.x = value;
        item.y = value;
        item.tickness = value;
    } else {
        item[property] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly, an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1JkN) what you're looking for?  I am really not following the example very well so I can't tell if this is what you mean, or if you're looking for something else.  In any case, you might want to elaborate with some more motivating code?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do here, there has got to be a better way.

Comment: Indeed, maybe my explanation was not perfect. Sorry. What do I want? I will want to have a single method with one parameter whose object type is the highest level one. Then, depending on the key I specify (object property or not), I want to call a very specific method that modifies the object. I think I should be able to make a key / function association. My functions would always have an input object and the new value to assign.

Comment: I will try your solution @jcalz

Comment: ... and it looks good to me. The best thing, to have a more fragmented and cleaner code, would be to be able to associate a key (property) with a function that will be called. In my main function, I find the function associated with the property and call it. I will try to find a solution from your answer. Thank you

Comment: I will probably write up my code as an answer, but if you want that key-function thing instead, you might want to change your question to give examples (specifically a [mcve]) of what you're talking about because I can't really guess, especially in the face of non-properties like `raz` and `all` (or *are* those properties?)